# Common View through Activities

Tags: android, view

I need to create multiple activities that will have a bar at the bottom of the screen. This bar contains three functions that are common to the activities. Can i keep the bar constantly on screen and switch through activities?

One way could be to load different fragments on the same activity, and let the bar be below the fragments.

But is it possible to switch between activities, without recreating the bar every time a new activity opens?

Comment: I think you answered your own question, Fragments.

Comment: Fragment with Tab or You can use fragment pager

Answer (score 1):

Possible option:

1. You have to create bottom layout bottomlayout.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/toolBarText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="2dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:text="TOOLBAR TEXT"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:textSize="15dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Include bottomlayout in every xml layout of activity.

   ```
   <include layout="@layout/bottomlayout"/>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments, is one way of doing it. Isn't there any other.